# Laravel sort the result are grouped by weeks

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-collection

Having a hotel booking application.

i want to get the `This Weeks` reservation count an `Last Weeks` reservation count.

so i achieved this with the below query, that gives the date by its week number. i want to sort it.

The query:

```
$byweek = Reservation::all()->groupBy(function($date) {
                                    return Carbon::parse($date->check_in)->format('W');
                                });
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Here `16` and `17` are week numbers, how can i sort it to get `17` and `16`?

Comment: or it would be better if u give a way to get two weeks count

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$byweek = Reservation::all()->groupBy(function($date) {
                                    return Carbon::parse($date->check_in)->format('W');
                                });

$byweek = $byweek->reverse();
```

**Done**

Get the all records and then reverse the collection to get the reverse 17, 16, 15 etc.. order.

Answer (score 3):

I think y try

```
$byweek = Reservation::all()
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at)'))
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(id)','desc'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is methods in Laravel collections `->sortKeys()` and `->sortKeysDesc()`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortkeys
PHP has `ksort()` function too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using orderBy inside the query and it works perfectly like this:

```
$byweek = Reservation::orderBy('check_in')->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
                                return Carbon::parse($date->check_in)->format('W');
                            });
```

don't forget that you have to use get() instead of all().
I tried this methods because I wanted the objects inside each week to be ordered and it works perfectly.